# Moving next input when press enter

Tags: jquery

I have a html table and it has text inputs in it. Some of them are disabled and some of them are enabled. I want to move the cursor to next input text when press enter. I'm getting closest tr and input with code down below but for instance; when first column finished then it goes to second column closest input text. But it should go to first one. How can I fix it?

[image]

```
if ($(this).closest('tr', 'td').next().find('.txt', ':enabled')[0] != undefined)
    $(this).closest('tr', 'td').next().find('.txt', ':enabled')[0].focus();
```

OR

```
$(this).parent().parent().next().find('.txt', ':enabled')[0].focus();
```

HTML Example:

```
<tr>
    <td>8:15-8:30</td>
    <td id="0_select_ 8:15" style="cursor: pointer; background-color: rgb(235, 151, 78);" runat="server">
      <input class="txt" id="0_selectbox_ 8:15" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td id="1_select_ 8:15" style="cursor: pointer;" runat="server">
      <input disabled="true" class="txt-none" id="1_selectbox_ 8:15" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td id="2_select_ 8:15" style="cursor: pointer;" runat="server">
      <input disabled="true" class="txt-none" id="2_selectbox_ 8:15" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td id="3_select_ 8:15" style="cursor: pointer;" runat="server">
      <input disabled="true" class="txt-none" id="3_selectbox_ 8:15" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td id="4_select_ 8:15" style="cursor: pointer; background-color: rgb(235, 151, 78);" runat="server">
      <input class="txt" id="4_selectbox_ 8:15" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td id="5_select_ 8:15" style="cursor: pointer; background-color: rgb(235, 151, 78);" runat="server">
      <input class="txt" id="5_selectbox_ 8:15" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td id="6_select_ 8:15" style="cursor: pointer; background-color: rgb(235, 151, 78);" runat="server">
      <input class="txt" id="6_selectbox_ 8:15" type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9:00-9:15</td>
    <td id="0_select_ 9:00" style="cursor: pointer; background-color: rgb(235, 151, 78);" runat="server">
      <input class="txt" id="0_selectbox_ 9:00" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td id="1_select_ 9:00" style="cursor: pointer; background-color: rgb(235, 151, 78);" runat="server">
      <input class="txt" id="1_selectbox_ 9:00" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td id="2_select_ 9:00" style="cursor: pointer; background-color: rgb(235, 151, 78);" runat="server">
      <input class="txt" id="2_selectbox_ 9:00" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td id="3_select_ 9:00" style="cursor: pointer;" runat="server">
      <input disabled="true" class="txt-none" id="3_selectbox_ 9:00" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td id="4_select_ 9:00" style="cursor: pointer;" runat="server">
      <input disabled="true" class="txt-none" id="4_selectbox_ 9:00" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td id="5_select_ 9:00" style="cursor: pointer; background-color: rgb(235, 151, 78);" runat="server">
      <input class="txt" id="5_selectbox_ 9:00" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td id="6_select_ 9:00" style="cursor: pointer; background-color: rgb(235, 151, 78);" runat="server">
      <input class="txt" id="6_selectbox_ 9:00" type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Simplified: `$(this).closest('tr').next().find('.txt:enabled:first').focus();`

Comment: Is your image correct?  You're saying you don't want to go right, but you want to go down, but to the pink one??

Comment: @Archer, yes it should go first one not closest one after last entry.

Comment: @kadr1 Sorry but that makes no sense.  Your image says to go down to the next row, to the pink one, which is up a row and to the right.  It sounds like you're saying you want to go down a row and stay in the same column, in which case it would be `$(this).closest("tr").next().find("input").first().focus();` which is (virtually) the same as what's already been suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is you want to move down one column and when you run out of inputs in that column start at the top of the next column and work down again. If this is correct:

...Unfortunately jQuery does not do column-based searches very well. You need a more intelligent iteration of the rows and columns, on a column basis:

### Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/fJn29/1/

```
        var $this = $(this);
        var $td = $this.closest('td'); // Current TD
        var $row = $td.closest('tr'); // Current TR
        var $rows = $row.parent(); // Current TABLE or TBODY - parent of all rows
        var column = $td.index(); // Current column of TD

        // Search on a row basis in current column, then try next column
        // repeat until we run out of cells
        while ($td.length) {
            // get next row
            $row = $row.next('tr');
            // If we were on last row
            if ($row.length == 0) {
                // Go back to first row
                $row = $rows.children().first();
                // And use next column
                column++;
            }
            // get the position in the row column - if it exists
            $td = $row.children().eq(column);
            var $input = $td.find('.txt');
            if ($input.length) {
                $input.focus();
                break;
            }
        }
```

You can make it wrap around if you like, by reselecting the first column if you run off past the last column:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/fJn29/2/

```
            if (column >= $row.children().length)
            {
                column = 1;
            }
            // get the position in the row column - if it exists
            $td = $row.children().eq(column);
```

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect solution for me.